# referencing instance names from linked class in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, instance-variables

I've got a linked class, with an external .as file, tied to a movie clip called "Menu" in an encompassing  fla. In this actionscript file, I am trying to pull some information from a few things I made with the flash authoring tool. There are a few symbols on stage in the fla that I drew with instance names "greensboro" and "birmingham", and I want to get their x-position inside some functions of the linked class.   I've tried returning a value from "greensboro.x" but of course it says the variable greensboro doesn't exist, because I haven't defined it in the class. Surely there is some way of getting that info in a variable of my linked class!

Edit: here is some code to show what I've tried(cutting everything else). This is in the .as file of the linked class:

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import fl.transitions.Tween;


    public class Menu extends MovieClip {

        public function Menu() {
        trace(birmingham.x);
        }

        public function get birmingham() : MovieClip {
        return root.getChildByName("birmingham") as MovieClip;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the MovieClip "Menu" available in the same FLA as the symbols named "greensboro" and "birmingham"? You should probably post some of your code, as it would be very helpful in locating the problem.

Comment: "greensboro" and "birmingham" are  symbols outside of this movieclip, but in the same fla. I don't know if I was clear on that.   I am trying to access these symbols from inside the linked class. Theres really no code trying to do this yet, so I have none to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, dudes.     Just figured it out...... I used BJornson's code in the linked class, but replaced `this` with `parent`. Here it is:

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;


    public class Menu extends MovieClip {

        public function Menu() {
        trace(birmingham.x);
        }

        public function get birmingham() : MovieClip {
        return parent.getChildByName("birmingham") as MovieClip;
        }
    }
}
```

Like magic! now I'm pulling x-value from MovieClip objects on the main fla's stage, and returning them for use inside my linked class! Super useful

Answer (score 0):

you can either make a public var inside the class like this:

```
public var birmingham : MovieClip;
```

and use it afterwards or create a getter like this to read out information:

```
public function get birmingham() : MovieClip
{
   return this.getChildByName("birmingham") as MovieClip;
}
```

in both cases you should be able to use birmingham.x

Answer (score 0):

```
xValue = this['greensboro'].x;
```

OR

```
xValue = this['birmingham'].x;
```

Comment: hmmm, I keep running into problems, with this I get "Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." Are you sure this works for movieclips outside of the assoiated classes movie-clip?

Comment: No that won't work. "this" refers to instances inside of the associated movieclip.

I havent tried this before. But try replacing "this", with the name of the MovieClip that they are inside of. If they are just on the stage then refer to root. That MIGHT work.

A bit more explanation on how you have everything set up would help me explain.

Comment: Heres how it works. I have an FLA called realsite.fla.  On its stage rests 2 movie clips with instance names greensboro and birmingham. On a later frame, there is another blank movieclip(still talking about the parent stage) called "Menu." This movieclip has a linked class, (in an external .as file). Inside this code (in the .as file), I am trying to get the x value of "greensboro" and "birmingham...." Thanks for taking the time to post and consider this problem.

Comment: No problem. You say, "On a later frame". Does that mean that greenboro and birmingham are no longer on the stage? When the FLA move moves to that new frame, if those MCs aren't on the stage in that frame then the external class won't be able to find them.

Comment: Well I just changed it to check and see if that was the problem, but I'm still getting errors. Right now the 2 MCs are at every frame that Menu is, so they can be called.   This is very frustrating, surely there should be a simple way